# Gray out button after 1 click - HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why does the below not work? I want it so when the button is clicked one, the JS still executes but the button is then disabled and 'grayed-out' so cant be clicked again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
    btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    var text = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    $.ajax({
      data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text": text
      }),
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: url
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button:disabled[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Call</button>
```

Comment: you set the attribute disabled  to disabled  ..

Comment: Where - I don't see.....its been a long day!

Comment: Actually it works for me, button gets disabled after the click.

Comment: It works for me too!

Comment: And me now :d Thanks to the edit! Thanks who ever you were!!

Comment: try with `prop()` .if above code not working. `btn.prop("disabled", true); // disable button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually re enable button after calling ajax command,There is two useful events to handle callback result of ajax call:

1. [success](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)
2. [error](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(e.target);
    btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
    var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    var text = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    $.ajax({
      data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
        "text": text
      }),
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("OK")
        btn.removeAttr("disabled");
      },
      error: function(data) {
        btn.removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button:disabled[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Call</button>
```